# Assign event time for Flink table created fromValues

Tags: java, testing, apache-flink, flink-sql

I want to create an dummy table in Flink Table API for testing purposes. For this I use the `StreamingTableEnvironment.fromValues` function. My program windows the table on event time, which is assigned to the column `time_ltz`. Here is my progress so far:

```java
@Test
public void build() throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setParallelism(2);
    env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(params);
    StreamTableEnvironment tEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);

    Table inputTable = tEnv.fromValues(
        DataTypes.ROW(
            DataTypes.FIELD("time_ltz", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP_LTZ()),
            DataTypes.FIELD("id", DataTypes.STRING()),
            DataTypes.FIELD("measurement", DataTypes.DOUBLE())),
        row(new Timestamp(10000L, "abc", 1.0));

    Table outputTable = inputTable
        .window(aggregationWindow.on($("time_ltz")).as("w"))
        .groupBy($("id"), $("w"))
        .select(
            $("id"),
            $("w").start().as("window_start"),
            $("w").end().as("window_end"),
            $("measurement").sum());

    tEnv.toDataStream(outputTable).print();
    env.execute();
}
```

Running this test results in the following error:

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: A group window expects a time attribute for grouping in a stream environment.
```

This makes sense, as `time_ltz` is not set as the event time. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to mark it as the event time. For the real input table I do it in DDL. Previously, I tried to construct a data stream, watermark it and then convert it into a table, but that seems more like a hack to me.

Comment: Is there any reason why You don't want to create `DataStream` and then convert it to table ?

Comment: We are not using DataStream at all, which is why we do not maintain POJOs for our sources or intermediate results. Therefore, I have to rely on tuples to feed to the data stream. Our source has 14 columns and dragging the type definition of a `Tuple14` around is really bothersome. I was just wondering if there is a better  way.